# Why Mongoose saves references of child ids in parent model?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to get into MongoDB and Node.js and found that the most recommended module to use is Mongoose. I liked the idea of creating a schema like mysql and it's pretty easy to use.

One thing I didn't understand is about the references.

```
var SessionSchema = new Schema({
    created: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    updated: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    client: { type: String, required: true },
    events: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Event', required: true }]
});


var EventSchema = new Schema({
    created: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    session: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Session', childPath: 'events', required: true },
    data: Schema.Types.Mixed
});
```

Now there is the question - Why do I need to reference event ids from inside the session? Why not to just query eventsModel.find({session: session._id})?

I'm afraid it will create huge session documents because a session can have even hundreds of events.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Is this your schema or are you referencing a doc or a tutorial that does this?

Comment: It's just some of the columns in the schema. Why are you asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well that depends,  usually the common path is to make those sort of reference for later to populate your query with the referencing data, as I extract from population documentation:

> there are no joins in MongoDB but sometimes we still want references
>   to documents in other collections. This is where population comes in.

if you are interested in population you make take a peak [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

you can do it manually no harm on that that depends of your needs and your queries.

Comment: Fair enough. I thought it might be a better implementation than just query "eventsModel.find({session: session._id})" (like I would do in mysql)